# How to verify if the user is soft deleted or destroyed

Tags: php, controller, laravel-5.4

So I'm starting my path on the front end development. I have a table with user description and a button that changes the state of the user. Everything except a validation works fine, the state is being changed and the page is refreshed correctly. Here is my code...

```
    public function changeState(Request $request)
    {

        if($request->ajax()){

            $usernames = Input::get('usernameSend');

            if(isset($usernames)){

                $user = User::Where('username', '=', $usernames);

                if ( !$user->get() ){ 

                    Log::warning("User not found.");

                } else {

                    if(!$user->get()->isEmpty()) { // verify if the user is active

                        $user->delete(); //soft delete the given user

                    }else{

                        $user->restore(); //removes the soft delete for the given user

                    }

                }

            }else{

             Log::warning("Username doesn't exist on database.");

         }

     }

 }
```

I'll explain what I find important on my logic

**if(isset($usernames))** -> verify if the username sent through the AJAX request is valid

**if ( !$user->get() )** -> verify if the user is on the database

**(!$user->get()->isEmpty())** -> verify if the user is soft deleted

I eventually want to add a function where one administrator can destroy a entry and although this works fine this way, the page is refresh and the user is vanished I think I should warn the user that the state wasn't changed and the user wasn't found in the database. But the **if ( !$user->get() )** is ignored even if I delete the user from the database manually and then run the script...been searching on the Database API but found nothing. What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Edit: To clarify a bit more here are some images to exemplify

The user is in the dabatase(working as intended)
[image]

I removed the user from the database(database is ordered by ID)
[image]

Still the same result(not working as intended)
[image]

When I refresh the page the entry is gone(what shows that I'm actually removing the entry from the database)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Laravel soft deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#soft-deleting)

> In addition to actually removing records from your database, Eloquent can also "soft delete" models. When models are soft deleted, they are not actually removed from your database. Instead, a `deleted_at` attribute is set on the model and inserted into the database. If a model has a non-null deleted_at value, the model has been soft deleted. To enable soft deletes for a model, use the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes` trait on the model.

Your user model must contain the `SoftDeletes` trait, such as:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;
    // ...
```

To check whether a user is soft deleted, use the `trashed` method:

```
<?php

$users = App\User::withTrashed()->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if ($user->trashed()) {
        // this user is soft deleted
    } else {
        // this user is not deleted
    }
}
```

Anything not in `$users` has been hard deleted.

You can restore any soft deleted record by doing:

```
$user->restore();
```

Comment: I've tried but I get this error
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2443: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::trashed()

Comment: Ok I've tried this and I get to the same...although it may simplify my code if I hard delete a record manually on the database, when I run this it still says that the user is there...my only guess would be the database entries are not being updated for some reason.

Don't know if it is relevant but I'm using MariaDB with phpadmin on wamp

Comment: Are you using the `SoftDeletes` trait in your user model? Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, althought I used first() instead of get(). Think the problem was on my first user->get() which wasn't behaving as I expected!
It all works now!! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use withTrashed if you want to restore from deleted records(soft).
Use this in 
 
`User::withTrashed()->Where('username', '=', $usernames)->restore();`

Comment: I can restore soft deleted records, my problem is to check if they are soft deleted or destroyed since somehow it just goes through the $user->get() even if the user is deleted manually on the database....

Comment: As you commented on @javier answer, seems there is some issue. Please check if your are performing manual operation on right database. If you have deleted record than it shouldn't be there not even if you are fetching with withTrashed.

Comment: Yeah that's what bugging me. Although your's and @javier way is the correct way I can't really think why this isn't working. Check my edit on the main post please.

Comment: Can you please check the database ? Same happened with me once later I found that I had almost same tables in two database and I was performing operations in different one. It could be possible so I would suggest please cross check once.

Comment: That's why I said to check the main post...when I refresh the page the entry I was operating on doesn't appear and as showned I'm displaying both trashed and non-trashed users. And I double checked my **.env** right now and all is correct. I don't have similar database names btw